# 3D graphics pipeline

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, directx, pipeline

That's what I understand about graphic pipeline (Opengl) so far, can someone confirm that?

- Object space: Object (geometry) specific coords;
- World space: rotate, translate and scale the object to world space;
- Eye space: Frustum that limits the world view, with a projection matrix that projects 3d 
  coord in a 2d plane (near plane?), scaling it when necessary and clipping it when its out of frustum/eye space

I've read that eye space reverses the Z axis, so, an original +z vertex turns backward from eye, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. There are

- Local Space

→ Modelview Transform →

- Eye Space

→ Projection Transform →

- Clip Space

→ Homogenous Coordinate w-normalization →

- Normalized Coordinate Space

The modelview and projection transform are usually expressed by a matrix multiplication. There are no special requirements on the matrices used, but you normally want them to be non-singular. But between that anything goes. The usually found transformations are rotation-scalings + translation and shear-scalings + translation.

> I've read that eye space reverses the Z axis, so, an original +z vertex turns backward from eye, why?

No, not really. I think you may maean negative z and w elements in the projection matrix. But that's only to get the depth ordering right. You could flip the sign of them just fine and reverse that effect by making certain adjustments to the depth range and depth test function. The negative sign there is just conventional to obtain a right-handed coordinate system with default settings, i.e. positive Z eye space coordinates come out of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you have any book recommendations?

Comment: Unfortunately right now there are no books I would recommend in total. Even the "Official OpenGL Programming Guide", aka the "Red Book" doesn't meet the standards I expect from an introductionary text. The IMHO best guide to modern OpenGL so far is Nicol Bolas' work, to be found at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut – occasionally I write on my own OpenGL "book" but unlike a tutorial this shall become a self enclosed work and it covers the full range of OpenGL-1 to OpenGL-4, as its also meant to be usable for people who have to maintain legacy code.

Comment: I can recommend you "Mathematics for 3D game programmin" by Eric Lengyel, it has good description about transformations (and how to calculate them)